# "set -x" in bash and ksh does not produce output for cron job

Tags: bash, cron, ksh

I have a script that I'm trying to debug.

The script runs perfectly from the command line, but when called with the same arguments in cron, it gives an application-specific error about not being able to transfer files.

In order to debug the issue, I added `set -x` to the second line of the script.  Now when I run it from the command line, I get a lot of detailed debugging output.

From cron, I get the original application-specific error without all the debugging output.

I've tried changing the shebang line from `#!/bin/ksh` to `#!/bin/ksh -x`, and I've even tried running the cron job with `/bin/ksh -x /usr/local/bin/theapp`.

I get no debug output.

I have also tried redirecting STDERR by appending `2>&1` to my cron job.

Am I missing some cron magic to get the debug output?

UPDATE: @barmar is correct, I should have posted my cron line:

`*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -x /usr/local/bin/myapp 2>&1`

Comment: How is this related to `bash`? Did you also try changing it from a `ksh` script to a `bash` script?

Comment: Bash and ksh are very similar.  I wrote a simple bash script that would echo 'hello' and tried to run it with -x.  From the command line it works, from cron you get no debug output.

Comment: Have you checked your email? Any output not redirected will be mailed to you.

Comment: I just tested with `/path/to/script >script.out 2>script.err`. The `-x` output was in `script.err`.

Comment: I get an e-mail, it's just the 'normal' output, not including STDERR even though I had `>2&1` at the end of my command.

Comment: If you have `2>&1`, `STDERR` will go to the file named in `>filename`, not the email.

Comment: Please add the entire crontab line to the question, we need to ensure you're using the correct redirection syntax.

Comment: Jobs running via `crontab` are not connected to your terminal session.  Any output (standard or error) not redirected to a file will be emailed to you.  The same applies to debug output produced by the `-x` option.  As you've now discovered, you need to add `> file` or `>> file` to your command.

Comment: I am aware of that @rojomoke.  Any output not redirected will be EMAILED to you.  So if STDERR is redirected to STDOUT, it should be EMAILED to me.  It wasn't.  The only way I can see STDERR on this server is to redirect it to a file.  I figured it might have been some Ubuntu weirdness.  Either way, I got what I needed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The cron line:

`*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -x /usr/local/bin/myapp 2>&1`

produces no debug output even though I have STDERR redirected to STDOUT.

I finally gave up and did:

`*/5 * * * * /bin/bash -x /usr/local/bin/myapp >> /tmp/cron.log 2>&1`

And the output shows up in the log.

Meh.